# Why do two distinct array literals equal each other in Swift?

Tags: swift

Why does the expression

```
import Foundation
["a", "b", "c"] == ["c", "b", "a"]
```

evaluate to **true** in a Swift playground?

(The expression evaluates to false when Foundation is not imported.)

Comment: My intuition is that the array literals are being interpreted as NSSet objects as a result of Foundation toll-free bridging.  But why NSSet rather than NSArray?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Josh's answer is close, but not quite right. Option-click on the equals operator. Your literals are `Foundation.CharacterSet`s.

```swift
public static func == (lhs: CharacterSet, rhs: CharacterSet) -> Bool
```

For literal resolution, the compiler is going to search

1. The module you're working in.
2. Your imports.
3. The Swift standard library. (Which has some special module-scope-disambiguation rule where implicitly-typed literals are Arrays, because that makes working with the language easier for the most part.)

[image]

Is this a bug of ambiguity? Yes. Is it resolvable? I doubt it. I bet it's broken because nobody has been able to get the performance to be good enough if it did an exhaustive search. But please, [log a bug](https://bugs.swift.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa), find out, and report back!

Comment: I'm curious why there isn't an equivalent of `IntegerLiteralType` for arrays: "The default type for an otherwise-unconstrained integer literal.", which would prefer `Array<T>` over `CharacterSet`.

Answer (score 2):

`Swift.Set` conforms to [`ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyarrayliteral) and it appears that when you compare two ArrayLiterals the compiler does in fact choose to evaluate them as `Set`'s.  you can confirm that its true by doing this:

```
import Foundation
let a = ["a", "b", "c"]
let b = ["c", "b", "a"]

print(["a", "b", "c"] == ["c", "b", "a"])
print(["a", "b", "c"] as Set<String> == ["c", "b", "a"] as Set<String>)
print(["a", "b", "c"] as [String] == ["c", "b", "a"] as [String])
print(a == b)
```

```
true
true
false
false
```

TLDR if you don't annotate the type of an array literal the compiler is free to coerce the type to any type that it chooses to infer as long as it conforms to ExpressibleByArrayLiteral.

Comment: So then it follows that the result of comparing array literals is undefined in Swift when Foundation is imported...

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.  In this situation the compiler selects the type and there is no rule as to whether it should be Array or Set.  So the result is undefined.  (Unless there is a rule that I am not aware of.)

Comment: If you want an array you ask for one with the type annotation.  Otherwise the compiler is correct in that its generally more efficient to compare sets and it can do a static compare and determine that these things are equal.

Comment: Unless there is a rule that says otherwise, a future version of Swift could (and probably should) interpret these array literals as Arrays rather than Sets.  Which is what I mean by the result of the comparison being undefined.

Comment: I feel like the behavior is correct as is; it checks for semantic equality of literals, which is actually a potentially useful behavior where as if it checked for literal equality it would be kind of pointless.

Comment: It's still strange that the results are different depending on whether Foundation was imported.

Comment: @TomHarrington This is less magical than it first appears.  Check my answer.