# Array equality is order-independent in a Swift playground?

Tags: arrays, swift

In a Swift playground (Xcode 13.2.1) this code runs fine

```
assert(["a", "b"] == ["b", "a"])
```

but in a real Swift app it crashes. The crash is what I expect. Why is the playground different?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I suspect it treats it as a set

Comment: If you command-click on the `==` operator (using the code `["a", "b"] == ["b", "a"]`), it will take you to the `==` function for `CharacterSet`, which conforms to `SetAlgebra`, so yeah they're being treated as sets instead of arrays.

Comment: `assert(["a", "b", "a"] == ["b", "a"])` evaluates to `true`as well

Comment: This answer might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65801142/988260

Comment: @TylerP Unrelated but why jump to definition doesn't work when I option-click on == operator (using 13.2.1)?